# Facebook PHP SDK Logging Out on Page Change

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session
>   cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at
>   /kunden/406064_81373/webseiten/lightningsoul
>   new/db/lg_db_login.php:25) in
>   /kunden/406064_81373/webseiten/lightningsoul new/fb/facebook.php on
>   line 49

I get this error when using the [fb SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk).

Here are lines 23-28 of the referred lg_db_login.php:

> ```
> $thisadress = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
> $thisurl = $thisadress;
> $dateiurl = explode('/',$url);
> $datei = explode('.',$dateiurl[1]);
> $shareurl = explode('&PHPSESSID',$thisadress);
> $shareurl2 = $shareurl[0];
> ```

I don't really get the error at all and I don't know why the login works and whenever I click on a link it logs a user out (or the login is not being recognized any more)... Check [this page](http://lightningsoul.com/?err=1) to reproduce the error.

Here are lines 47 to 55 of the facebook.php (original, I changed nothing in that):

```
  public function __construct($config) {
    if (!session_id()) {
      session_start();
    }
    parent::__construct($config);
    if (!empty($config['sharedSession'])) {
      $this->initSharedSession();
    }
  }
```

Comment: on which line you have session_start() function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue is about **session_start();** function you should write it add first line after `<?php`

```
<?php
session_start();
```